# Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "producttype_productitem" does not exist

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jax-rs

During the process of educating myself on JAX-RS and JPA. I stumbled upon the following exception when i ran the project on Glassfish server 3.1.2 . However JPA implementation is working fine as a standalone application.

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
>   **ERROR: relation "producttype_productitem" does not exist**   Position: 65 Error Code: 0 Call: SELECT t1."productCode", t1.COST,
>   t1.ITEMCODE, t1.ITEMNAME FROM ProductType_ProductItem t0,
>   "ProductItem" t1 WHERE ((t0.ProductType_productCode = ?) AND
>   (t1."productCode" = t0.item_productCode))     bind => [1 parameter bound]

---

I am using Eclipse Kepler IDE , Glassfish Server 3.1.2 ,Jersey for JAX-RS, Eclipselink 2.3 for JPA Implementation and PostgresSQL for database.

---

```
CREATE TABLE "ProductType"
(
  "productCode" integer NOT NULL,
  "productName" character(50) NOT NULL,
  "productType" character(50),
  rate numeric(18,6),
  count integer,
  CONSTRAINT "PrimaryKey" PRIMARY KEY ("productCode")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "ProductType" OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "ProductType" TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "ProductType" TO public;




 CREATE TABLE "ProductItem"
(
  "productCode" integer NOT NULL,
  "itemCode" character(20),
  "itemName" character(20),
  "cost" numeric(10,6)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "ProductItem" OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "ProductItem" TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE "ProductItem" TO public;
```

---

**Entities**

```
package com.jaxrs.crud;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@Entity
@Table(name="\"ProductType\"")
@XmlType(name = "product")  
public class ProductType implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name="\"productType\"")
    private String productType;

    @Column(name="\"productName\"")
    private String productName;
    @Id
    @Column(name="\"productCode\"")
    private String productCode;

    private Float rate;
    private int count;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductItem> item;

    private ProductType(String productID, String productType,
            String productName,float rate) {
        this.productCode = productID;
        this.productType = productType;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.rate = rate;

        ProductItem item1 = new ProductItem();
        item1.setCost(new Random().nextFloat());
        item1.setItemCode("ITC"+new Random().nextInt());
        item1.setItemName("ITN"+new Random().nextInt());
        if(item == null )
        {
            item = new ArrayList<ProductItem>();
        }
        item.add(item1);

    }
    public ProductType()
    {

    }

    public ProductType(int count) {

        this("PID"+new Random().nextInt(),"PTE"+new Random().nextInt(),"PNE"+new Random().nextInt(),new Random().nextFloat());
        this.count = count;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productType
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "productCode")
    public String getProductType() {
        return productType;
    }

    /**
     * @param productType
     *            the productType to set
     */
    public void setProductType(String productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productName
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "productName")
    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    /**
     * @param productName
     *            the productName to set
     */
    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productID
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public String getProductID() {
        return productCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param productID
     *            the productID to set
     */
    public void setProductID(String productID) {
        this.productCode = productID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rate
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "rate")
    public Float getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    /**
     * @param rate
     *            the rate to set
     */
    public void setRate(Float rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    /**
     * @return the count
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "cnt")
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * @param count
     *            the count to set
     */
    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itemList
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "items") 
    public List<ProductItem> getItemList() {
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemList
     *            the itemList to set
     */
    public void setItemList(List<ProductItem> itemList) {
        this.item = itemList;
    }

      @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new StringBuilder().append(this.productCode).append("  ").append(this.productName).append("  ").append(this.productType).append("  ").append(this.rate).append("  ").append(this.count).toString();

    }
}
```

**ProductItem Entity**

```
package com.jaxrs.crud;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@Entity
@Table(name="\"ProductItem\"")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "productCode","itemCode", "itemName", "cost" } )  
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
public class ProductItem {
    @Id
    @Column(name="\"productCode\"")
    private String productCode;
    private String itemCode;
    private String itemName;
    private Float cost;

    /**
     * @return the itemCode
     */
    public String getItemCode() {
        return itemCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemCode
     *            the itemCode to set
     */
    public void setItemCode(String itemCode) {
        this.itemCode = itemCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return the itemName
     */
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    /**
     * @param itemName
     *            the itemName to set
     */
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cost
     */
    public Float getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    /**
     * @param cost
     *            the cost to set
     */
    public void setCost(Float cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    /**
     * @return the productCode
     */
    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param productCode the productCode to set
     */
    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }



}
```

---

**JPA invocation**

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("jaxrs");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();

    List<ProductType> results = null;
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM ProductType p",
                ProductType.class);
        results = query.getResultList();
        for (ProductType pt : results)
            System.out.println(pt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    return results;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this could work in standalone without some changes.  ProductType Entity has a @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) relationship to ProductItem which will require a relationship table defaulting to name "ProductType_ProductItem".

This doesn't seem correct as I find it strange that both ProductType and ProductItem have a productCode used as their IDs.  This seems like a OneToOne relationship between them.

Regardless, the OneToMany is not set up correctly unless you plan to use a relation table.  It should be removed or changed so that the table or joincolumn you wish to use is specified.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing in ProductType class

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductItem> item;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "\"productCode\"")
    private List<ProductItem> item;
```

By this i understood that  JoinColumn should be used in unidirectional relation to specify the persistence provider the foreignKey (here productCode is FK in ProductItem)

However the former still works when i just run it as standalone which is

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("jaxrs");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory
            .createEntityManager();

    List<ProductType> results = null;
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM ProductType p",
                ProductType.class);
        results = query.getResultList();
        for (ProductType pt : results)
            System.out.println(pt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

    return results;
```

Trying to analyze this. Will post if i find anything.

Thanks.