# javax.ejb.EJBException and org.postgresql.util.PSQLException try to show a list

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jpa

hi this error appears when I try to run my web app, I want to list o person in a a web page via jpa these are the errors in the trace

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no existe la    relacion 'persona'  Position: 116 Error Code: 0 Call: SELECT IDPERSONA, CELULAR, MAIL, ESTADO, IDENTIFICACION, NOMBRE, PRIMERAPELLIDO, SEGUNDOAPELLIDO, TECNOLOGIA FROM PERSONA Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Persona sql="SELECT IDPERSONA, CELULAR, EMAIL, ESTADO, IDENTIFICACION, NOMBRE, PRIMERAPELLIDO, SEGUNDOAPELLIDO, TECNOLOGIA FROM PERSONA") at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
```

My facade sessionBean....

```
@Stateless
public class PersonaFacade extends AbstractFacade<Persona> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jasperUtilPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public PersonaFacade() {
    super(Persona.class);
}
```

part of my Controller Bean...

```
@ManagedBean(name = "personaB")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonaBean {
private List<Persona> ListOfpersona;


@EJB PersonaFacade personaFacade;
public List<Persona> getListOfpersona() {
    ListOfpersona= personaFacade.findAll();
    return ListOfpersona;
}........
```

and the web page is....

```
    <h:body>

   <h:dataTable border="1" value="#{personaB.listOfpersona}" var="Persona">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                idpersona
            </f:facet>
            #{Persona.idpersona}
        </h:column>
```

is not a error for a related table (is a single table persona) like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906829/internal-exception-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-error-relation-productt)

and the entity class look well...

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Persona.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Persona p")
public class Persona implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="PERSONA_IDPERSONA_GENERATOR",       sequenceName="SEQ_GENA")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,  generator="PERSONA_IDPERSONA_GENERATOR")
private Long idpersona;
```

I don't know where error is??

other error....

```
FATAL: JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.el.ELException durante el procesamiento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=/index.xhtml @19,80 value="#{personaB.listOfpersona}": javax.ejb.EJBException
```

2)

```
FATAL: /index.xhtml @19,80 value="#{personaB.listOfpersona}": javax.ejb.EJBException
```

Comment: the table persona is exists in your database right?

Comment: yes!! this is the script of created table in postgres CREATE TABLE persona
(
  idpersona bigserial NOT NULL,
  estado integer,
  identificacion bigint NOT NULL,
  nombre character varying(255),
  primerapellido character varying(50),
  segundoapellido character varying(50),
  celular character varying(20),
  email character varying(150),
  tecnologia character varying(20),
  CONSTRAINT cliente_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idpersona)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE persona
  OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: usually, this kind of error happened because of not referencing the table name correctly. could you try to use quote like this `select * from "persona"` or in your case, set the name variable in your entity annotation to `\"person\"`?

Comment: did you mean?? @NamedQuery(name="Persona.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM \"Persona\" p") ...this is the entity annotation.. and shows me an error ---- abstract schema type is unknow

Comment: No, I mean on the `@Entity` annotation there is a field called name which you use to assign the name of the entity. or maybe you could try to use `@Table` annotation and also assign the name of it.

Comment: <pre>@Entity(name= "Persona")
    @Table(name="persona")
    @NamedQuery(name="Persona.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM     Persona p")
    public class Persona implements Serializable {<code> is still having the error

Comment: try `@Entity(name="Persona")` and `@Table(name="\"persona\"")`

Comment: Work!! shows me the web page (index) but without data!! I added a button for send data to a pdf and tells me: actionListener="#{personaBean.ExportPDF}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'personaBean' resolved to null

Comment: check your controller, probably because either your personaBean variable is null in your controller or your personaBean should be personaB?

Comment: how do I check if my personaBean variable is not getting data? i've trying to change personaB.ExportPDF to personaBean.ExportPDF but don't get the data!! ... I used breakpoint --> ListOfpersona= personaFacade.findAll(); but I run the debugging doesn't stop there

Comment: maybe it's because your controller bean name is `PersonaB` so you should use `#{personaB.exportPDF}`. and your breakpoint is set on method `getListPersona()` which I think is totally different method right?